# Can I get a bigger tilde with URW Schoolbook?

Tags: amsmath, math-fonts

I am using URW Schoolbook L for a project. The use of `\tilde{}` gives the expected results of having over tilde on the symbol. However the default tilde symbol is too small as you can see in the result of the MWE appended. Is there any way to change the size of the tilde in the default `\tilde{}` command?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

The tilde in this $\tilde{T}$ is too small. Can it be made bigger?
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Personally, I find the tilde has the right size.

Comment: @egreg any specific design/typographical reasons for this?

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

The tilde in this $\tilde{T}$ is too small. This one $\widetilde{T}$ is
not.

\end{document}
```

[image]